# How to properly say that agreement is still valid/on?

Tags: phrases

For example, we agreed with a friend to meet in a week, and the day before the meeting I want to make sure nothing has changed about the agreement.

So I'd come up with something like

> Are we still meeting tomorrow?

Is there a better (shorter) way to say/ask this?

Comment: That's pretty short and it's something a native would say. Anything shorter and you start to lose information. You might ask, "Are we still on for tomorrow?" (1 word longer) "Tomorrow's still a go?" (1 word shorter) But really your question hits the nail on the head.

Comment: I was looking for a more general phrase (not necessarily a meeting, could be some kind of agreement as well) In my first language (Russian) we have something that would litteraly mean "deal is in force" or "all is in force". I'm sure there has to be something like that in English, too. So maybe something like "deal is on"?

Comment: No, don't say "deal is on."  English requires the use of articles much more often that Russian seems to. The best I can come up with is an informal, "We still on?" which leaves the what, when and where to context and/or imagination. But if those are well understood "We still on?" is idiomatic.

Comment: "to be on" is a good option, thanks!

Comment: "The deal (or agreement) still stands" is another expression used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your phrase is perfectly expectable. The only obvious shortening would be:

> Are we still on?

You could shorten it further to:

> We still on?

But at some point you aren't really gaining anything. Other alternatives:

> Are we still on for tomorrow?
>
> You still up for lunch tomorrow?
>
> We still good for lunch?
>
> Is tomorrow still good?

And so on. Most of these, by the way, are extremely informal and are primarily heard in purely conversational English.

Comment: +1 Great variety of answers, and all sound perfectly natural to this native American English speaker.  In addition, one might say informally "Are you still down for lunch tomorrow?"  Or "Is lunch tomorrow a go?"

Comment: Is it correct to say "are you still on"? Meaning "I am on, but how about you?"

Comment: @Alex Yes, that is also correct.

Comment: What would be a more formal way to express this? Is "Are we still meeting tomorrow?" acceptable in business communication?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. You could also say something more assertive like, "I am calling/writing to confirm our meeting for tomorrow at 2pm."

Answer (score 1):

If both parties have been clear about what was planned, when and where it was to occur, you could simply say

> Still on?